# VBA Macros to open Multiple file path store in one cell

Tags: vba, excel

Could anyone help me with a macro that can open nultiple file path store in one cell

File path are stored in Column H and I

H1 can have file file path or multiple and same for I

For Example, if 1 file path is found, it will return as below
`1,C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\work\287497196_DN.pdf`

And if 2 file path are stored, separted by a comma
`2,C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\work\Order_9250_TA_0580484707_Copy_of_del._note_XXX_signed_by_cust..TIF,C:\Users\XXXX\Desktop\work\Order_9250_TA_580484707_Customer_e-Mail.EML`

The numbers in the start indicates the number of files found in a cell with file path

The files can be PDF, .TIf or .EML

Please help me how can I open all file if I click on that particular cell

Would be really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Not have much time to write complete code, but try using something like:

```
newArray() = Split(Range("H1"), ",")
For i = 1 to Ubound(newArray)
     Documents.Open newArray(i)
next i
```

So this will split your text with file paths using comma delimiter into an array.
After that you'll loop through array (note that 1st array element is zero, so that your loop starts from 2nd element)